# How can I estimate a table size in HIVE without query?

Tags: database, hadoop, hive

I want to calculate the table size without querying in HIVE.

How can I do this in HIVE? 
(I don't have any permission without selecting in database so I can't use show properties, etc)

(For example)

- dataRows : 100
- columnName(Type) : userName(string), userNumber(int), userCode(bigint), userAge(int)

  - maximum length of userName : 36

I calculated table size like this.

- I thought like that string is 8bytes, int is 4bytes, bigint is 8bytes
  (I didn't consider about record header size and column header size)

  - 100 * ((8*36)+4+8+4)
  - totalSize : 30,400 bytes

Would you give me some advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
hdfs dfs -du -s {table locatoin}
```

(optional -h)

E.g.

```
hdfs dfs -du -s /user/hive/warehouse/mytable
110265307244  /user/hive/warehouse/mytable
```

---

```
hdfs dfs -du -s -h /user/hive/warehouse/mytable
102.7 G  /user/hive/warehouse/mytable
```

Comment: Thank you for answering the question. But I don't have any access permission about HIVE. So I have to estimate my table size without query.

Comment: You need access to the HDFS

Comment: I really want to get a permission but I can't.

Comment: This does not seem like a technical issue but a organization issue. If you need this information get the access or find someone with access thta can supply it to you.

Comment: Yes, I know it. But I wonder some way to estimate a size of tables. Because when I use the relation database, there is some way to calculate it.

Comment: Does G stand for GB?

Answer (score 1):

This is not really possible if you have no access to Hive or HDFS.

Hive could be using different compression mechanisms and that could impact the size of the raw data on HDFS as well. If its stored in plain text, you could potentially use this, but I wouldnt say thats the best way to do this.

Comment: Thank you for answering the question.